# Update different Database & and tables

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

I've two database and three tables. My goal is when I updated the item and code column in my `database1 table1`. All of the same code and name in `database2` and `table1/table2` should also be changed. If it possible to changed in one query?

I used this line code below to determine what database I used.

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "database1");
$mysqli1 = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "database2");
```

Here's my database structure.

**Database 1 - Table 1**

```
id -|- Item -|- Code
-----------------
1   | Pencil |  pen001
```

**Database 2 - Table 1**

```
id -|- Item -|- Code
-----------------
1   | Pencil |  pen001
```

**Database 2 - Table 2**

```
id -|- Item -|- Code
-----------------
1   | Pencil |  pen001
```

Comment: Hi user, consider creating an account with StackOverflow and coming back more often! That way we can get back to you if help doesn't come immediately :)

Answer (score 0):

> If it possible to changed in one query?

What for? There is not a single reason to do it in one query

> All of the same code and name in database2 and table1/table2 should also be changed

It seems that you don't need extra database at all. If you 're looking for some sort of home-brewed **replication** - then look for original solution from mysql

Comment: This sounds like an answer to me. "It's a bad idea" is an acceptable answer.. and he even provided a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Even your requirement is not much clear but if you want this then you can achieve this by below 2 ways.

1. [By replication on same server](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replication-options-slave.html#option_mysqld_replicate-same-server-id).
2. You can achieve by trigger, so whenever you do any change in your main db/table trigger will do the same changes in db2/tbl1 and tbl2.

But this can slow your db.

Comment: First of all your question is that how 2nd db and tables can update automatically, further what about if any new row inserted in db1 or deleted from here in all cases you need to execute 2 queries...first of all why are you want this duplicity while there are other easy and effective options like replication etc. are available. So if you share your need then this community can help you to get best option.